# What does calling a function inside pipe, return in gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I know the [pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) function in NodeJs. A readable stream calls the pipe function with the first argument being the writable stream. Something like:

```
readable.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.txt'));
```

This will pipe all the output to `file.txt`. But I have not understood this in context of `gulp`.

What does a call to a pipe function like:

```
gulp.src('./assets/styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass());
```

mean? Here is the full snippet:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

// require sass
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./assets/styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/styles'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

I understand the `dest` part. But do not understand the `pipe(sass())` part. What does it do? What stream does each of these functions return?

Note: I have taken the sample example from [a blog](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/quick-intro-to-gulp-js/)

Answer (score 1):

The `pipe` in gulp is the exact same as the `pipe` in Node.

This flow streams the sources files from `.src()` and creates a new stream a pipes it through the sass plugin - the sass plugin will then process all sass files into css and concat them to the destination path as a new stream.